# What type of component is the handle of QToolbar?

Tags: c++, qt

[`QToolBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html) has a handle (marked in red):

[image]

What is the actual component, which is used as a handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qtoolbar.cpp.html#_ZN8QToolBar10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent) of `QToolBar` shows, that the handle is painted in the following way:

```
opt.rect = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ToolBarHandle, &opt, this);
if (opt.rect.isValid())
    style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorToolBarHandle, &opt, &p, this);
```

The documentation of [`QStyle::PrimitiveElement`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#PrimitiveElement-enum) says:

> `QStyle::PE_IndicatorToolBarHandle` `36` `The handle of a toolbar.`

---

If you want to change the look of the handle using stylesheets, the `QToolBar` section of the [Qt Stylesheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) says:

> The handle (to move the toolbar) is styled using the [`::handle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#handle-sub) subcontrol.

[For example:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtoolbar)

```
QToolBar::handle {
    image: url(handle.png);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but Qt style sheet not supported for custom QStyle subclasses, right? i want to change style sheet for it

Comment: @TuyenNH, please, see what I have added to my answer.

Comment: @TuyenNH, you are very welcome! You could now mark the answer as accepted and if you like it, please consider upvoting it, once you reach 15+ reputation.